# How to connect Button in activity main...java, android studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, button

I created Live Streaming application by using ZegoCloud. Everything is working but now I want to replace buttons, in video example was Name,id, and then you click go live and Live stream starting. How can I make...click on button and go live directly without typing my name?  Because registration page I created now separate....and if host wants to go live them can make it by just clicking on button and start live, no need entre name or id many times, same for customers...sorry I'm new in it. I hope for your help.))))
If you have any source code for streaming application would be happy, like Liveme, bigo....just to understand how to connect Button

I tried to change it in activity main but was error

Button startLiveButton = findViewById(R.id.start_live_button);

```
    startLiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
```

And sorry no clue what to do next
Java

Answer (score 0):

The logic is simple. *setOnClickListener* belongs to step 2.

1- You create the button.

2- You create an instance of *OnClickListener*

3- assign that *OnClickListener* to that button using *btn.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)*; in your
fragments/activities onCreate-method.

4- When the user clicks the
button, the *onClick* function of the assigned *OnClickListener* is
called.